# Applicability of Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I am working through Larry Wasserman's All of Statistics. I am trying to understand why Hoeffding's Inequality was valid for the following problem:

> Suppose we test a prediction method on a set of $n$ new test cases. Let $X_i=1$ if the predictor is wrong and $X_i=0$ if the predictor is right. Then $\bar{X}_n = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is the observed error rate. Each $X_i$ may be regarded as a Bernoulli with unknown mean p. We would like to know the true - but unknown - error rate p. We have that $V(\bar{X}_n)=\frac{V(X_1)}{n}=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ and from Chebyshev's inequality
> $$P(|\bar{X}_n-p|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{p(1-p)}{n\epsilon^2}\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}$$

The author then assigns $n=100$ and $\epsilon = .2$ to demonstrate that Hoeffding's inequality is more accurate. However, why is Hoeffding's inequality applicable here? By definition:

> Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be independent observations such that
> $E(Y_i)=0$ and $a_i\leq Y_i \leq b_i$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, for any $t > 0$,
> $$P(\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i \geq \epsilon) \leq e^{-t\epsilon}\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{t^2(b_i-a_i)^2/8}$$

What is bothering me is the condition that $E(Y_i) =0$. How is this the case in the example mentioned above? From the example, isn't $E(X_i) = p$? And we do not know if $p$ is zero or not, so how can we use Hoeffding's inequality here?

Comment: $Y_i=X_i-p$, so if $E[X_i]=p$, $E[Y_i]=0$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!